# Electrolytic Substrate modification to enhance corrosion resistant of reactive metal

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis, electroplating

So, I was working on a project lately. The project I was working on involves the utilization of inexpensive, non-toxic, and inert electrodes. Unfortunately, the only substrates I have access to are copper, aluminium, and iron plates. Now, my assumption was to coat these substrates with inert, inexpensive metal oxide articles like lead dioxide and manganese dioxide. Clearly though, the lead dioxide won't be an option as it can be potent, leaving me with one option.

I tried heating the freshly HCl etched iron plate while applying a thin layer of manganese nitrate. However, as it formed, the plate started rusting and then gradually darkened. I was confused for a moment, so I tried cooling the plated substrate and applied 30% hydrogen peroxide to make sure we have got manganese dioxide, not magnetite. Upon testing, the misty gas generation confirmed the test.

The next step was a corrosion test. In the experiment, I placed the control and the newly plated electrode in 20% brine with a 1 amp current draw for 180 sec. After examination, they both formed hydroxides with different oxidation states II and III, respectively. Consequently, this disproved my hypothesis.

**Question:**
What went wrong in the process?
Is there any pre-treatment that I could perform?
Are there any chances or possibilities for any of the remaining substrates?
Are there any inexpensive accessible articles that can be utilized instead?

**NB: I planned to use the plated the substrate in electrolysis without it being involved in the actual reaction. Therefore, I did not want to just prevent it from corrosion caused by oxygen but prevent it from further corrosion caused by electrolysis**

Comment: You should absolutely separate the treatments of the electrodes. Anodes and cathodes do not behave in a similar way in electrolysis. Probably only anodes must be protected against corrosion. But I don't know if it is possible to prevent anodic oxidation of usual metals like copper, aluminium or iron. The best way (and maybe the only way) is using a noble metal like platinum as an anode.

Comment: An anode reaction is essential to the cell therefore the anode must either be involved in the reaction or be inert and a conductor to supply electrons to the anode reaction. Painting the electrodes is a good way to stop electrolytic reactions. That is corrosion prevention. What is your reaction? An anode must be less reactive. Two choices: use a less reactive material or chose an anode reaction that is more easily oxidized.

Comment: @jimchmst my intention was creating an anode that is both inert and allows circulation of electron .Certainly, I never wanted an anode that involves on the chemical reaction or completely insulated electrode that doesn't circulate electron.